# Glassfish/Jersey finding deleted files when scanning for REST resources?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, jersey

I am getting errors in NetBeans when I try and deploy my REST service. The log shows that it is finding three root resource classes in `com.mypackage.io` which is incorrect as only the `Resource` class actually exists.

It was originally `ResourceABC` but I renamed it to `Resource`. The class `ResourceXYZ` is a class I deleted. All these classes map to the same path `"/"` which is why my REST service fails to load. So why is Glassfish/Jersey picking up these classes when they don't even exist anymore?

```
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.mypackage.io
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.mypackage.io.Resource
  class com.mypackage.io.ResourceABC
  class com.mypackage.io.ResourceXYZ
```

Comment: I just renamed `Resource` to `Bug` and deployed to Glassfish, which naturally failed. Then I renamed `Bug` back to `Resource` and when I attempt to deploy again it shows `Bug` as being one of the `Root resource classes found` along with other three resource classes mentioned above. This makes no sense, how is it picking up these classes that were deleted/no longer exist in this package?

Comment: Sometimes Glassfish gets confused when redeploying an app from Netbeans, have you tried to first undeploy the app and then redeploying? In case this is not even working, try to delete files in the "generated" subfolder under the Glassfish domain folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.xml.

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        ...
    </servlet>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase of gradle project, kindly do gradle clean  and check

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).